# How to ship a Spring Boot app from a Gradle Multi Build project?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, groovy, gradle-multi-project-build

Let's say I have a Gradle Multi Project with 3 subprojects, 2 Spring Boot projects (`auth` and `profile`) and 1 Library project (`commons`).

The 2 Spring Boot projects include a dependency on the Library project: `implementation project(":commons")`

Actually, to run the 2 Spring Boot projects, I have to run this from the parent project:

```
gradlew auth:bootRun
gradlew profile:bootRun
```

If I run `gradlew bootRun` only, from each Spring Boot subproject, I get the Error like the `:commons` Library project is not found in the root project, which makes sense, because the `:commons` project is included only in the parent's `settings.gradle` file.

I have to push each Spring Boot subproject individually to Heroku.

How should I manage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it, just add this in each subproject's `settings.gradle` file, then build:

```
include ":commons"
project(':commons').projectDir = new File('../commons')
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a `settings.gradle` in each sub-project in the first place. If you do, it is no longer a multi-projet but rather completely separate, unrelated projects. And if this is on purpose because you really don't want to structure it as a multi-project for some reason, you should look into [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).

Comment: Ok, that is probably why I still have a problem with deployment. I was able to run the app locally, but when I push it to Heroku, I have the same error, the project `:commons` is not resolved. Please can you check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64891154/how-to-deploy-on-heroku-a-gradle-spring-boot-app-with-dependency-on-a-local-lib